Logging to multiple services with OpenTelemetry in a single project
The background is fair simple: I'm building a Modular Monolith, and I'd like to have the logs as if they were microservices already.
My idea here was to have an ActivitySource per Module, and wire that ActivitySource to an specific source, so when exporting and using the logs, the Module name would pop-up instead of a shared-project-service-name.
Any clues?

What you ask is how ActivitySources are used in all projects. You can have as many as you want in any project and name them any way you want. You aren't forced to use the project name. If there's only one in the project it's because someone decided to only create a single ActivitySource. If you want more, create more

ActivitySources correspond to OpenTelemetry traces. The number and names are those you want to see in monitoring tools like Jaeger or Open Search. You should create different ones per modules, just as there are different ones for ASP.NET, HttpClient or EF. Only the service name is unique in a .... service. The micro in microservice is silent, essentially just a marketing term

In short, what's the problem? What's stopping you from using multiple ActivitySource objects?

The problem here is that when using multiple ActivitySource there is no way to link them  to different Resource/Service.
And if it is as you said, it cannot be done.

That's not the case, otherwise you wouldn't be able to use ASP.NET Core's or EF Core's telemetry in your application. Both use their own ActivitySources. It's the application's configuration code that says, this OTEL setup which we call a Service, that listens to these sources, and exports to those targets, shall be named X. You don't need multiple service names now. Should you extract some part as a service (the "micro" prefix is just a fashion label and thus silent), you'll have to configure logging and tracing in each service again
